# Scraping information from previous pages using LinkExtractors

Tags: python, scrapy

I wanted to know if it is possible to scrape information from previous pages using `LinkExtractors`. This question is in relation to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026352/changing-next-page-url-within-scraper-and-loading)

I have uploaded the answer to that question with a change to the xpath for country. The xpath provided, grabs the countries from the first page.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class ZooplasItem(scrapy.Item):
    stuff = Field()
    country = Field()

class ZooplasSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'zooplas'
    allowed_domains = ['zoopla.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.zoopla.co.uk/overseas/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='a.link-novisit'), follow=True), # follow the countries links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='div.paginate'), follow=True), # follow pagination links
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[contains(@class,'listing-result')]"), callback='parse_item', follow=True), # follow the link to actual property listing
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # here you are on the details page for each property
        loader = ItemLoader(ZooplasItem(), response=response)
        loader.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
        loader.add_xpath("stuff", "//article[@class='dp-sidebar-wrapper__summary']//h1//text()")
        loader.add_xpath("country","(//ul[@class='list-inline list-unstyled'])[1]//li//a//text()")
        yield loader.load_item()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        settings = {
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36',
            'FEEDS': {
                'zoopla.jl': {
                    'format': 'jsonlines'
                }
            }
        }
    )
    process.crawl(ZooplasSpider)
    process.start()
```

However, this prints out the following output:

```
'country':'(//ul[@class='list-inline list-unstyled'])[1]//li//a//text()'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CrawlSpider` is meant for cases where you want to automatically follow links that match a particular pattern. If you want to obtain information from previous pages, you have to `parse` each page individually and pass information around via the `meta` request argument or the `cb_kwargs` argument. You can add any information to the `meta` value in any of the parse methods.

I have refactored the code above to use the normal scrapy `Spider` class and have passed the country value from the first page in the meta keyword and then captured it in subsequent parse methods.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class ZooplasItem(scrapy.Item):
    stuff = Field()
    country = Field()

class ZooplasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zooplas'
    allowed_domains = ['zoopla.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.zoopla.co.uk/overseas/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # grab the countries links and follow them
        # you can do some other parsing here and pass the information down to the subsequent parse methods
        for link in response.xpath("(//ul[@class='list-inline list-unstyled'])[1]/li"):
            country = link.xpath("./h4/a/text()").get()
            url = link.xpath("./h4/a/@href").get()
            yield response.follow(url, meta={"country": country}, callback=self.parse_country)

    def parse_country(self, response):
        # follow link to individual listing and pass the country value in the meta object
        # you can pass any information in the meta dictionary
        for link in response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'listing-result')]"):
            yield response.follow(link, meta={"country": response.meta.get("country")}, callback=self.parse_item)

        # follow pagination links
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_country)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # here you are on the details page for each property
        loader = ItemLoader(ZooplasItem(), response=response)
        loader.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
        loader.add_xpath("stuff", "//article[@class='dp-sidebar-wrapper__summary']//h1//text()")
        loader.add_value("country",response.meta.get('country')) # retrieve the country name from the 
        yield loader.load_item()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        settings = {
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36',
            'FEEDS': {
                'zoopla.jl': {
                    'format': 'jsonlines'
                }
            }
        }
    )
    process.crawl(ZooplasSpider)
    process.start()
```